# Is there any way to control the IE version used by CDHTMLDialog

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2012, version, dhtml

I'm building an app for a controlled environment.  I started using CDHTMLDialog (Visual Studio 2012) thinking it would be quick and easy, but am rapidly finding that there is very little documentation.  I've been able to figure most things out, but I keep running into gotchas due to the version of IE that the OLE control is using.

I have IE9 installed on this system running Win7 (and since it's a controlled app, I can guarantee that for all installs).  First, I noticed rounded corners don't work, so I figured it must be IE8.  Then I noticed that border-spacing doesn't work, but cellspacing does, so it must be using IE7.  Is there any way to get whatever this class is using updated to a current browser engine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying control is per default in IE6 compatibility mode. You can switch the browser version in CDHTMLDialog and similar by adding the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

This allows you to use things like SVG, modern CSS features, etc. To always use the maximum version of IE available, you can change the above to use `IE=Edge`.

Comment: This answer may come too late for gbryant. I added it nevertheless, since I stumbled over the same question recently.

Comment: Umm, better late than never? :)  I'm trying to think back to three years ago, now, and IIRC we gave up on that approach and just went with WPF.  Not nearly as "open" as I would have liked, and we are now looking at new options to open up using Linux for our kiosks.  More work overall, but things are still growing, so as a next step that might make sense.  Still, worth marking as a valid answer.  Thanks.